# How to display more EditText in AlertDialog in appcelerator studio

Tags: javascript, android, appcelerator-alloy

I'm building a simple app with appcelerator studio. So I want to display in one AlertDialog two EditText. It is possibile to do this?

Now I'm building this code:

```
      var textfield = Ti.UI.createTextField();

      var dialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
          title: 'Enter text',
          androidView: textfield,
          buttonNames: ['OK', 'cancel']
      });
      dialog.addEventListener('click', function(e){
          Ti.API.info(textfield.value);
      });
      dialog.show();
```

but with this code, I can see only one EditText.

Comment: Try in the title to use a escape to new line "Enter text \n Second line" and see if it will show 2 lines now

Comment: mm no, because I this mode I can't display some information, I want to see 2 EditText